# Stateless auto configuration IPv6 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, ipv6, ping

I have installed ubuntu 12.04. i heard that ethernet interface automatically get a link local address but in my ubuntu box it's not getting link local address.

Command

```
ifconfig -a
```

output

```
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:a1:a2:50  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:19
```

when i trying to assign it manually using command

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 add fe80::21b:38FF:FEa1:a250/64
```

it assigned to interface eth0.
but when i try to ping it using

```
ping6 -I eth0 fe80::21b:38FF:FEa1:a250
```

it gives

```
connect:cannot assign requested address ping6 ubuntu
```

command

```
ip -6 route get fe80::21b:38FF:FEa1:a250
```

gives

```
fe80::21b:38ff:fea1:a250 from :: via fe80::21b:38ff:fea1:a250 dev eth0  metric 0 
cache
```

this may have some clue for someone.

Comment: tried solution, add lines in /etc/network/interfaces [auto etho] and iface eth0 inet6 auto

Comment: Please provide additional information by editing your question and not in a comment. That way the relevant parts are easier to find.